# React inherit html from super class

Tags: reactjs, inheritance

I am building a series of gadgets and want to have a super class where some general gadget UI is defined such as a header bar container min/max/close button and maybe a footer and only the content area of the gadgets are defined in subclasses.

Any suggestions?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need to use inheritance here at all. There's a good discussion on the React Docs about [Composition vs Inheritance](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment).

It sounds to me like you should have a 'parent' component that defines the header/footer etc, and `props.children` to render the content. For example:

html

```
<Gadget>
  <GadgetOne></GadgetOne>
</Gadget>
```

js

```
function Gadget(props) {
  return (<div><header />{props.children}<footer /></div>);
}

function GadgetOne(props) {
  return (<div>...</div>);
```

Comment: Your solution is the first solution came up to my mind but I did think that this is an inheritance pattern instead of composition (which cause a lot of redundant codes). I found a solution myself. See my answer below. Hopefully someone has a better one.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer myself:

For the super class:

```
export default class Gadget extends React.Component{
    renderHeader() {
        return (
            <div>header</div>
        )
    }
    renderMe() {
        return null;
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.renderHeader()}
                {this.renderMe()}
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

For the subclass:

```
import Gadget from '../../../../common/Gadget'
class ENGAlertsGadget extends Gadget{
    /**
    * render
    * @return {ReactElement} markup
    */
    renderMe(){

        //...
        return (
            <div id="ENGAlerts" style={{"height":"250px", "backgroundColor":"#58D3F7", "borderRadius":"10px", "margin":"9px", "padding":"9px"}}>    

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<ENGAlertsGadget/>
```

The key points are
 - HTML code is not redundant
 - You never want to expose the super class in your HTML